# Remainder Dividing Repunits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $n = 11111 \ldots 1$ (1 repeated 123 times.)

Then find the remainder when $n$ is divided by 271?

I know I can write this in the form of a sum of a gp but it doesn't help to find the remainder...

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: A somewhat unpleasant way is to first calculate $9n$ modulo $271$ using the binary method for exponentiation, and then solve a linear congruence. The inverse of $9$ modulo $271$ is easy.

Comment: You can start calculating the remainders of $10 ^n$ modulo $271$: $10^3\equiv187$, $10^4\equiv244$, $10^5\equiv1$. Bingo! This means that $10^5-1=99999$ is divisible by $271$. Because $\gcd(9,271)=1$ it follows that $11111=(99999/9)$ is also divisible by $271$. The rest goes as in JuanTheron's answer. The method of remainders of powers of ten is handy when you can cancel the factor nine. Caveat: it may take a while to find the smallest exponent that works. Because $271$ is a prime elementary group theory tells us that the smallest exponent is a factor of $271-1=270$.

Comment: (cont'd) But it could have been $135$ or $270$. So we can consider ourselves lucky. Or may be not? For this to be solvable in reasonable time some trick needs to work - and this is one of the more popular ones, so...

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381805/to-calculate-the-remainder-of-111-222-333-444-555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ When $\displaystyle 11111$ Divided by $271\;,$ We get a remainder $0$

So We Can Write it as a pair of $5,s$ one form..

So $ 111111........(\bf{123-times})= \underbrace{11111}_{\bf{5-times}}\underbrace{11111}_{\bf{5-times}}..............................\underbrace{11111}_{\bf{5-times}}\underbrace{111}_{\bf{3-times}}$ Times

So when we Divide the above no. by $271\;,$ We get Remainder $111$

Comment: How did you stumble upon  that 11111 is a multiple of 271

Comment: This is nice but only works in such a special case. E.g. if you wanted the remainder modulo $275$ it would be much harder to try to make it work this way. However, I guess in some problems like this they purposely build in some structure like what you found, and when you do find it, it makes things very easy. So +1.

Comment: since $41\cdot 271=11111$

Comment: @Sudhanshu If you're really good with arithmetic in your head I guess you could just "see" it. If you're allowed to use a calculator you could try dividing a string of 1 by 271 for various length of string starting with length 4, and see if you get any perfect multiple. Otherwise you have to build up the remainders by hand, repeatedly multiplying the remainder by $10$ and then adding 1 and then get the new remainder.

Comment: @user2566092 Your way of finding the remainder  makes it so much easier to find that 11111 leaves remainder 0.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $9$ and $271$ are relatively prime, you can note your remainder is the remainder of $(10^{124}-1)*9^{-1}$. Thus if you get the multiplicative $x$ inverse of $9$ that gives you a remainder of 1 for $9x$, then all you have to do is compute the remainder of $10^{124}$ and subtract one and then multiply by $x$. To get the remainder of $10^{124}$, you can start with $10$ and then keep squaring to get the remainder of $10^2, 10^4, 10^8$, etc., and then multiply together the remainders of powers that add up to $124$. (The base-2 representation of 124 will tell you which powers of 10's remainders to multiply together. I.e., you multiply the remainders of the powers that are $10^{2^k}$ where the $k+1$th binary digit in $124$ base-2 expansion is 1. You can keep taking remainder as an intermediate step while you are multiplying remainders of powers.)

Comment: This will work like charm, because $10^5\equiv1\pmod{271}$. Therefore repeated squaring will result in repetitions sooner rather than later. Then you will know what to do :-)

Comment: I didn't get the part : " multiplicative x inverse of 9"

Comment: It's $-30$, which is easy to see because $9 \cdot (-30) = -270 = 1$ when you calculate the remainders when you divide by 271. Anyway I just meant find the number so that when you multiply by $9$ and then take the remainder when you divide by $271$, you get $1$. That's the "multiplicative inverse." of 9. This method in my answer will work for any divisor, not just $271$, just as long as the divisor is not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

First you find $\frac{1}{271} = .\overline{00369} = \frac{369}{99999} 
                              = \frac{369/9}{99999/9} 
                              = \frac{41}{11111}$

So $\frac{11111}{271} = 41$

Then do what @juantheron did.