# To calculate the remainder of (111...) + (222...) + (333...) + (444...) + (555...) + (666...) +(777...) by 37

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> To Evaluate the remainder

**Question**:

$ (111...) + (222...) + (333...) + (444...) + (555...) + (666...) +(777...)$ mod $37$

In each bracket, the single digit $(1, 2, 3, ..., 7)$ is written $110$ times next to itself.

I know that: **(a+b)%m=((a%m)+(b%m))%m** but the question is how to evaluate the **individual modulus** and add and again take modulus.

How do I proceed further? Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:
$$\underbrace{11\cdots111}_{110\text{ times }}(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)$$

Now $\underbrace{11\cdots111}_{n(\ge1)\text{ times }}=\dfrac{10^n-1}9$

Now $10^3\equiv1\pmod{37}$ and $110\equiv2\pmod3\implies10^{110}\equiv10^2\pmod{37}$

and $9\cdot4\equiv-1\pmod{37}\iff9^{-1}\equiv-4\equiv33$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $111=3\cdot 37$ so you can drop repeated digits in bunches of three.